# QGIS: sip module implements API v11.0 to v11.3 but the qgis._core module requires API v10.0

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, open-source-gis, boundless-suite, sip

I have read all the questions on the SIP module and QGIS, but they do not answer my question.  Most of these are dealing with screwed up paths; I do not think my environment variables are incorrect.

I've got a Windows 7 x64 system running Boundless Desktop 1.0 (QGIS 2.14 Essen).  I set its python install to be the primary system python, and have been pip-ing a bunch of libraries I need.  Here are my user environment variables:

```
GDAL_DATA = C:\Boundless\osgeo4w\share\gdal
GDAL_DRIVER_PATH = C:\Boundless\osgeo4w\bin
PATH = [path variables],C:\Boundless\osgeo4w\bin;C:\Boundless\osgeo4w\apps\qgis\bin;C:\Boundless\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\Scripts
PYTHONHOME = C:\Boundless\osgeo4w\apps\Python27
PYTHONPATH = C:\Boundless\osgeo4w\apps\Python27;C:\Boundless\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\Boundless\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\DLLs;C:\Boundless\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\Lib
```

When I start QGIS, I am faced with this:

```
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v11.0 to v11.3 but the qgis._core module requires API v10.0
```

When I check sip within a python shell, I get the following:

```
>>>import sip
>>>print(sip, sip.SIP_VERSION_STR)
(module 'sip' from 'C:\Boundless\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\sip.pyd'>, '4.18.1')
```

When I check sip from the command line, I get the following:

```
C:\>sip -V
4.14.7
```

So I've got a mismatch between two versions of sip.  The QGIS error indicates that it is looking for an older version.

I have, since installing and configuring QGIS, updated GDAL (to 2.1.3) and PyQt4 (to 4.8.6).  My feeling is that these actions have broken QGIS, and my question is this:

Is there a particular version of GDAL/PyQt4 I can just downgrade to, or would the better option be to reinstall QGIS, thereby (hopefully) overwriting and replacing the offending libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just went ahead and reinstalled QGIS over top of the existing install.  It didn't wipe out any optional libraries I had already installed (pandas, requests, etc) and set gdal/sip back to the compatible versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pip install pyqt5-sip
```

It worked for me.